# Who is M. Montel?

Tags: math-history, mathematicians, mathematical-french

From V.I. Arnold's Experimental Mathematics:

> Not having achieved what they desired, they pretended to desire what they had achieved.
>
> –M. Montel

Who is M. Montel? Is he related to the French mathematician [Paul Montel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paul_Montel). Or is it the same person? Does M. stand for Monseigneur?

Comment: In French, "M." can stand for "Monsieur," i.e. "Mr.".

Comment: M. = Monsieur (Mr.). Mme = Madame (Mrs.).

Comment: If Monseigneur, then abbreviated incorrectly.

Comment: @ClementC. But isn't it rare to see such titles (like Mister/Monsieur etc) in a *quote*? At least in English literature what I usually see is addressing the name directly without any title.

Comment: Not that rare, actually. One difference with English would be that the title Dr, Prof, etc. is very seldom (if ever) used, and M. is much more common. (Even when referring to, say, a president.)

Comment: I have done it. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The "Montel" cited by Arnold is almost surely Paul Montel, the only one of his name who has gained posterity. It was an usage, say till the fifties, not to use that much given names "Hilbert has proved", not "David Hibert...". You will find many instances in old texts where people are reverently called "M. Hilbert" or "Herr Hilbert" :)

Comment: True, but in that book it seems this style is not used throughout. I'd speculate the M. at this specific place  is an error.

Answer (score 1):

If the quoted phrase  is about mathematics, certainly it is of Paul Montel the M. corresponding to"Monsieur". Apparently, as far as I know, the name of Paul Montel does not appear practically never in English books. But in the French school there is even the adjective "montelian".  A Montel space, for example, is in France a locally convex metrizable, complete space in which every bounded subset is relatively compact.  For example the space of holomorphic functions on an open $U\subset \mathbb C^n$ provided with the topology of compact convergence is Montel.

Comment: I am not convinced this is the *reason* for the M., it could just as well be a pure typo, or a confusion due to the usage you mention  being employed *elsewhere*. I cannot check in detail but it seems that other names for quotations in the book are given differently.

Comment: It may be that you're right. However, it seems that there is no other Montel quotable in the world of mathematics. Moreover, it is not unlikely that Arnold wanted to show some affection for both, Montel and thought "Monsieur" as that in France there are  extraordinary super-doctors no called doctor by people but Monsieur. Something towards your opinion could be if that there are other French cited in the book of Arnold and see if they also are named with the blessed M.

Comment: Poincaré is just Poincaré.

Comment: Without H.? (of Henry)

Comment: Yes. (It is below a quote Landau to Poincaré) Some other names are given with initials. As said, I cannot check in detail. These are just those I found in the part of the book I found online.

Comment: I think now that your speculation  about a misprint has increased probability.